# Tomcat 5.5 Don't Find My Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I've compiled the source into the class `Files`, then putted at the folder:

```
Tomcat 5.5\WEB-INF\ROOT\classes\Files.class
```

And added this to the `web.xml` file:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Files</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>Files</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

But when I tried to access the URL `http://localhost:8080/Files`, I got this error from Tomcat:
[Tomcat 5.5 404 Error http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/5042/tomcat404.png](http://img251.imageshack.us/img251/5042/tomcat404.png)

---

**Update**: after adding `<servlet-mapping>` I'm now getting the following error:

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error allocating a servlet instance
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:837)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:640)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1287)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: IllegalName: /Files
java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1960)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:931)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1405)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1284)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:837)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:640)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1287)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Note that putting Servlet classes in default package is discouraged. Tomcat is lenient in this, but in certain Tomcat configurations and in other servletcontainers you risk that the servlet cannot be located/loaded. Always put classes which are to be loaded/imported by another classes inside a package.

Comment: I know, but this is only a simple test. Then I've didn't used the packages.

Comment: It might be the root cause of this problem. Read server's startup logs in `/logs`.

Comment: @BalusC: Just to make sure, the file is  like this: http://freetexthost.com/ys4x6i116n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> root cause
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: IllegalName: /Files
> ```

This means that the given class definition cannot be found because it has an illegal name `/Files`. This in turn means that you've changed the `<servlet-class>` to `/Files`. This is wrong. You're basically instructing the servletcontainer to declare and instantiate the servlet as follows:

```
/Files Files = new /Files();
```

This won't already compile. The complete mapping should look like:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>instanceName</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.ServletClass</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>instanceName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/urlPattern</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Which is to be interpreted in raw Java code as follows:

```
com.example.ServletClass instanceName = new com.example.ServletClass();
```

The `<servlet-class>` should denote the **full qualified classname**, including any package. The `<servlet-name>` should denote the **unique instance name**. The `<url-pattern>` should denote the **URL pattern** for which the servletcontainer should invoke this servlet.

Answer (score 3):

You also need to define a

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Files</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/Files</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

To match the url pattern to the servlet

Comment: You may need to restart Tomcat, or at least reload the application.  Did you try that?

Comment: Of course, I've already tried all, re-compile and restart the server.

Comment: Are you sure you only put "/Files" in the url-pattern, and no where else?

Comment: @fd: Just to make sure, the file is like this: http://freetexthost.com/ys4x6i116n

Comment: This is incorrect: <servlet-class>/Files</servlet-class>
You need: <servlet-class>Files</servlet-class>

Answer (score 3):

You also need the servlet-mapping:

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Files</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/Files</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, in you classes folder under WEB-INF, make sure you make a folder whose name is the same as the package name of the classes and put all the classes in that folder. In web.xml, use

`<servlet>
  <servlet-name>File</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>package.File</servlet-class>
</servlet>`

to reference you servlet in the classes folder